# I get MailService.Send message, but my mail isnt coming to adres

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

My **main.py**

```
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="<ada******@gmail.com>",
                            subject="Your account has been approved")
message.to = "<*****.ada@gmail.com>"
message.body = """
            Please let us know if you have any questions
            """
message.send()
```

I use Google App Engine `MailService` for the following console output:

```
INFO     2015-05-11 17:21:46,179 mail_stub.py:143] MailService.Send
From: <ada******@gmail.com>
To: <*****ada@gmail.com>
Subject: Your account has been approved
Body:
Content-type: text/plain
Data length: 317
```

But the mail isn't coming to address `*****.ada@gmail.com`. What is the problem?

Comment: are you trying to do that locally? also the sender should be one of the admins of the app..

Comment: Maybe the emails are in the spam folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on the development server you need a mail server to use: see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Python_Using_Mail) how you can use **Sendmail** or **SMTP server**.
But ([here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail) at the bottom):

> When your application is running on App Engine, it uses the App Engine
>   mail service to send email messages.

So, even if on the dev server you cannot send emails they will be sent when you deploy your code on App Engine.

Comment: Thanks, yes I deployed and got the mail:)